# Remove drag event listeners while dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I remove drag event listeners while dragging an element? I want to remove a card while dragging if a certain condition gets true, but even if I set all drag listeners to `null` the `drag` and `dragend` events are called.

```
d3.select("#"+card.id)
    .on("dragstart", null)
    .on("drag", null)
    .on("dragend", null);
```

I could also handle this in the drag and dragend methods, but I guess it should be possible to prevent further calls to these methods by setting the event listeners to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

d3.select("#"+card.id).off("drag");

Comment: The latest version of d3 (which I use) has no .off()